# Manage BLoC pattern in a wizard with Flutter navigation

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm wondering about how could you approach in the best way handling of the BLoC pattern with a large wizard i.e. 10 pages.
I have some questions.

1. Is it recommended to create one BLoC per page of wizard?
2. Could I create one BLoC with the basic states (Loading, Error, Main) and on each page iteration call something like
   state.add(state.copyWith('new_values')) (where state is Main state).
3. Is not easier to send the data from the previous page to the next?

Answer (score 0):

I have production app with a 7 steps wizard(which collects a lot of data) and I use single bloc for that.

The BloC is global(I don't pass it from page to page) and pages just fill the data in the wizard. At the end of the wizard I have another bloc which takes the collected data and sends is to the API to create the content.

In my case, I only collect the data and at the end the user submits.

If you need to hit the API for every page, then I will advise you to create BLoC for every page and pass the data to the next one.

Comment: yes, and also I guess if you have some api rest between pages you could create events and after that invoke the api and alter the same state with something like state.copyWith(new_value). I think that there are many ways though